# SQL QUERY FOR COUNT

Tags: sql, count

HOW TO DISPLAY FIRST AND LAST ROW VALUE FROM THE TABLE BY USING COUNT

EXAMPLE:

```
ID   TIME   DATE

001  10.00  02:10:2009 
001  02.00  02:10:2009 
001  23.00  02:10:2009 
002  04.00  03:10:2009 
002  12.00  03:10:2009 
002  22.00  03:10:2009 

SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS TIME FROM TABLE
```

OUTPUT IS

```
ID      date       TIME

001   02:10:2009    3
002   03:10:2009    3
```

For 001 Time count is 3 Then time is 10.00, 02.00, 23.00
For 002 Time count is 3 Then time is 04.00, 12.00, 22.00

I want to display min(time) and Max(time) from the count value

Exactly i need

For 001 min(time) is 02.00 max(time) is 23.00 for the particular date

SQL Query?

Comment: How to get min(time) and Max(time) for the particular date and id - sql query help

Comment: (merged 2nd question into main question)

Comment: Not get a correct query - please

Comment: What's wrong with Gregs answer?

Answer (score 8):

Try something like

```
select id, 
  count(*) as time_count, 
  min(time) as min_time, 
  max(time) as max_time 
from table
group by id, date;
```